# Is there a way to order Wagtail Blocks in the Admin Panel

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, admin, wagtail

Currently I have all blocks split out into different groups for the page editors to easily navigate through the different block options. However, from reading the documentation I cannot see any way to specifically order the groups.

[image]

It would be great to be able to customise this so that I could have the text editor group at the top, the image group/carousel block next to each other etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently supported - as of Wagtail 4.1, groups of blocks are always listed alphabetically by group name. [Here's where this is implemented](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/4ee7a633b656a6b1791f46a59b2eff44d6f0e288/wagtail/blocks/stream_block.py#L87-L101).

You could probably override this behaviour by subclassing StreamField and defining your own `grouped_child_blocks` method, but be aware that this isn't an officially documented method and could potentially be changed or dropped without warning in a future Wagtail release.

Comment: I suspected this was the case, thanks for your response, and keep up the great work!